Calculating Binding Energy of Th 230 nucleus
Ok this is NOT a homework question. But it’s somewhat related. Please bear with me.
In calculating BE of Th 230, I used the rest mass of proton as 1.007276u and rest mass of neutron as 1.008665u (as provided by some online resources/data sheets) and after using mass defect of 1u = 931.5MeV, churning out the binding energy: it comes up to 1709 MeV.
But in another resource, the BE was recorded as 1755 MeV. It used the rest mass of proton as 1.007825u.
Ok so this discrepancy did cause some homework problems but really why is 1.007825u used? Why are there two values for mass of proton?

see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66342/proton-mass-and-weizsäckers-formula?rq=1

Note that for heavy nuclei, atomic masses are known more precisely than nuclear masses, and electronic binding energies (including relativistic corrections for the most tightly bound inner electrons) are non-negligible in the atomic masses. It is easy to get in the weeds, especially when using "some online data sheets." Furthermore, total binding energy is only useful if you are planning on dissociating the nucleus completely; consider whether a differential quantity like the mass excess is more appropriate for your application.

The 2020 Atomic Mass Evaluation gives the mass excess at 30.8625 MeV and a binding energy per nucleon of 7630.997 keV, and an atomic mass of 230.033132

The best way to measure the nuclear binding energies of a nucleus is to measure the atomic mass of that particular isotope, and subtract that from the masses of hydrogen atoms and the masses of neutrons. There is no problem with the electrons' masses this way, because they cancel out; the only errors you incur will be the electron binding energies. Even overestimating the electron binding energies of Thorium by using sum of $Z^2$ and just multiplying 13.6eV, the error incurred is 3.36MeV, much smaller than your discrepancy. To improve it, find the ionisation potentials of Thorium.

Consulting a table of all the ionisation potentials of Thorium, their sum is 0.719895574MeV, much smaller than the 3.36MeV rough estimate I gave earlier. Subtracting the 90 copies of H atom 13.6eV, we get 0.71867MeV, which, I think you can agree, is far smaller than the discrepancy that you are seeing. Nuclear binding energies are just that much bigger, that you really ought to do things this way, or else you will be in serious difficulties. Now, if you take the mass of proton and mass of electron and mass of Hydrogen atom, you will find that the precisions involved cannot get 13.6eV.
